# How to get the contents of a webpage in a shell variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

In Linux how can I fetch an URL and get its contents in a variable in shell script?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You can use `wget` command to download the page and read it into a variable as:

```
content=$(wget google.com -q -O -)
echo $content
```

We use the `-O` option of `wget` which allows us to specify the name of the file into which `wget` dumps the page contents. We specify `-` to get the dump onto standard output and collect that into the variable `content`. You can add the `-q` quiet option to turn off's wget output.

You can use the [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command for this aswell as:

```
content=$(curl -L google.com)
echo $content
```

We need to use the `-L` option as the page we are requesting might have moved. In which case we need to get the page from the new location. The `-L` or `--location` option helps us with this.

Comment: This is a really neat trick. I invoke a shell script via a php script on a proxy server. When asked, the proxy server turns on expensive servers which shut themselves off after 2 hours. I need the output from wget for standard output to feed back to the Jenkins console record.

Comment: i am yet to get this... can anybody demostrate as to how , for eg. get an img tag in a variable for this link http://www2.watchop.io/manga2/read/one-piece/1/4 ??

Comment: @juggernaut1996: that should be a separate question. Briefly, you have to download the page, extract the `src` attribute of the correct element, then download *that* page. If you install [tq](https://github.com/plainas/tq), this command should do it: `curl -s http://ww1.watchop.io/manga2/read/one-piece/1/4 | tq -j -a src "#imgholder a img" | xargs wget`

Comment: Wget 1.14 version is not accepting `convert_links = on` with `-O-` option. It is failing with error `-k can be used together with -O only if outputting to a regular file.`. Is it expected?

Comment: Note, if the URL includes a query string with multiple elements (eg separated by &), then the URL needs to be in "" quotes, otherwise it will only wget up to the first & and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 39):

There are many ways to get a page from the command line... but it also depends if you want the code source or the page itself:

If you need the code source:

with curl:

```
curl $url
```

with wget:

```
wget -O - $url
```

but if you want to get what you can see with a browser, lynx can be useful:

```
lynx -dump $url
```

I think you can find so many solutions for this little problem, maybe you should read all man pages for those commands. And don't forget to replace `$url` by your URL :)

Good luck :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd double quote the url's.

Answer (score 9):

There is the `wget` command or the `curl`.

You can now use the file you downloaded with wget. Or you can handle a stream with curl.

---

**Resources :**

- [linux.die - man wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)
- [linux.die - man curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `curl` or `wget` to retrieve the raw data, or you can use `w3m -dump` to have a nice text representation of a web page.

```
$ foo=$(w3m -dump http://www.example.com/); echo $foo
You have reached this web page by typing "example.com", "example.net","example.org" or "example.edu" into your web browser. These domain names are reserved for use in documentation and are not available for registration. See RFC 2606, Section 3.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
content=`wget -O - $url`
```

Comment: @rjack: (But the article you linked to does make a pretty good case for the $(...) syntax.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) installed, it provides a binary simply named "[GET](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-request)".

```
$ GET http://example.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <TITLE>Example Web Page</TITLE>
</HEAD> 
<body>  
<p>You have reached this web page by typing &quot;example.com&quot;,
&quot;example.net&quot;,&quot;example.org&quot
  or &quot;example.edu&quot; into your web browser.</p>
<p>These domain names are reserved for use in documentation and are not available 
  for registration. See <a href="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt">RFC 
  2606</a>, Section 3.</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

`wget -O-`, `curl`, and `lynx -source` behave similarly.

Answer (score 2):

No curl, no wget, no ncat, nothing? Use `telnet`:

```
$ content=$(telnet localhost 80)
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: close
 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

```
$ echo $content
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 22 Mar 2021 12:45:02 GMT Server:
Apache/2.4.46 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.1.1j Last-Modified: Mon, 31 Dec 2018
15:56:45 GMT ETag: "a4-57e5375ad21bd" Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 164 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8 Success! 192.168.1.1
```