# How to read/search specific content in a webpage using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, html

I'm a beginner in shell scripting.

I'm trying to write a script in which a part of it involves reading the value from a webpage. In this case, The shell script tries to fetch the IMDB rating of a movie by going to the movie's IMDB page.

Can someone suggest me how i can achieve this & also what are the topics i need to learn ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wget and curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742983/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-webpage-in-a-shell-variable) to get the page. Then you'll need to use [regex or some other string manipulation](https://loige.co/extracting-data-from-wikipedia-using-curl-grep-cut-and-other-bash-commands/) to get the information you need from that. It would be a lot easier to use a [library](http://suriyadeepan.github.io/2016-08-25-scrapy-guide/) to do some of these things for you.

Comment: mandatory [don't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552) link.