# How to execute a URL from a command line without opening a browser on linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, url, redhat

I want to create a shell file to run a URL without opening the browser, it could have been run in Windows but in Linux does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) utilities available on Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the contents of a webpage in a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742983/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-webpage-in-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP request from the command line using `wget`, or `curl`, or `lynx`, or `perl` (with the `WWW::UserAgent` module), or `nodejs` (with the `fetch` or `request` modules), or `php` (with the `file_get_contents` function), or a host of other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This has been done in windows in a bat file so that the execution of the URL is programmed every 7 minutes now I would like to migrate it to linux as I migrate the method with its user and pass parameters.

```
    @if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal
set "URL=http://......."
cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%URL%"
goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var x = WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),false,"user","pass");
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);
```