# how to scrape the binance price in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to scrape the binance price

I play arround with.

```
price1=$(echo -s https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHBTC | grep -o 'price":"[^"]*' | cut -d\" -f3)
echo $price1
```

I got the price but also an error like:

line 15: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHBTC:

No such file or directory

someone can explain me how to use it correctly maybe

finally I like to have it in dollar

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742983/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-webpage-in-a-shell-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742983/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-webpage-in-a-shell-variable)

Comment: cool thank you iam not far away from the solution :-)

Comment: curl https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHBTC > tmp_file
cat tmp_file | grep 'price":"[^"]*' | cut -d'>' -f4 | cut -d'<' -f3

Answer (score 0):

`echo -s` doesn't do anything special on my Linux. It just prints `-s`.

Use [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se) to download the data and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to process it.
It is as simple as:

```
curl -s 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHBTC' | jq -r .price
```

The arguments of `jq`:

- `.price` is the `price` property of the current object (`.`).
- `-r` tells it to return raw data; the value of `.price` is a string in the JSON downloaded from the URL.